# C# winforms detail datagridview not responding when a new parent record is added

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Using visual studio 2019 and sql server 12

I have implemented a master detail relationship in winforms. The parent record is shows in a form and the child records for that parent row are shown in a datagridview. Things work fine as long I view the existing records. However, when I add a new parent record, the child datagridview is still stuck at the last parent (persisted) record viewed. The new record has a temp id of -1. I use an autogenerated id in the db. The db has a foreign key constraint. When I added the detail table to the dataset, the relationship appeared but the constraint did not. I tested with and without the constraint, but there is no change in behavior.

I have read others reporting that they were not able to save the detail records because of the temp id. For me when I add a new child row, it is linked to a different parent record, not the new parent record.

There is a many to many relationship between ResearchActivities and Contacts. The three tables involved are ResearchActivities, Contacts and ResearchActivitiesContacts. I am treating ResearchActivity as the parent here and ResearchActivitiesContacts as the child.
Sharing some code:
**relationship**
            fkc = new global::System.Data.ForeignKeyConstraint("FK__ResearchActvityContacts__ResearchActivity", new global::System.Data.DataColumn[] {
                        this.tableResearchActivity.ResearchActivityIDColumn}, new global::System.Data.DataColumn[] {
                        this.tableResearchActivityContacts.ResearchActivityIDColumn});
            this.tableResearchActivityContacts.Constraints.Add(fkc);
            fkc.AcceptRejectRule = global::System.Data.AcceptRejectRule.None;
            fkc.DeleteRule = global::System.Data.Rule.None;
            fkc.UpdateRule = global::System.Data.Rule.Cascade;

**binding source for child**
            this.researchActivityContactsBindingSource.DataMember = "FK__ResearchActvityContacts__ResearchActivity";
            this.researchActivityContactsBindingSource.DataSource = this.researchActivityBindingSource;

```
        this.researchActivityBindingNavigator.BindingSource = this.researchActivityBindingSource;
        this.researchActivityContactsBindingNavigator1.BindingSource = this.researchActivityContactsBindingSource;
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell where it went wrong, without any code.

Comment: @user994124:   Did you try `dataGridViewName.Refresh();` ??

Comment: @D J. Thanks for the suggestion. Tried the refresh in the click event of the add new button. Maybe, I am calling the refresh sooner than I should. Do you have suggestions for any other event where I can call the refresh?

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen Not sure what parts of the code you want me to share

Comment: @user994124 : How are you implementing the master detail relationship ? With the BindingSource Component ? How do you add the record ? manually ? by using the bindingsource.AddNew() method ?

Comment: I used the designer for both. The relationship between the master and detail table in the dataset allowed me to pull the detail table on to the form. That automatically made the parent's bindingsource as the datasource for the child. For adding rows, I used the bindingsource navigator, relying on VS to add the rows. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your bindingNavigator should be bound to your ParentBindingSource, and your childBindingSource to the child member of your ParentBindingSource.

Assume you have two tables : Customers (Parent) as customersBindingSource and Contacts (Child) as contactsBindingSource. So Contacts have a foreign key of the customer they are linked to.

So contactsBindingSource should be linked to customersBindingSource. Something like :

```
this.contactsBindingSource.DataSource = this.customersBindingSource;
this.contactsBindingSource.DataMember = "CustomersContacts";
```

From there, all child (contacts) are linked to parents (customers).

Hope that helps, as we really don't know how you implemented this relation. As Jeroen van Langen said, sharing parts of your code showing how you implement this relation would be appreciated.

Comment: Added some code snippets. Things work fine as long as I am looking data already in the db. The problem is only when I create a new parent record (in my case ResearchActivity). Also, once I save the new record, I am able to add child records. During the time between creating and saving, the child datagridview(s) show stray data (actually child records of the last persisted parent record viewed).

Comment: Try this and let us know the result : Suscribe PositionChanged Event to researchActivitiesBindingSource (researchActivitiesBindingSource.PositionChanged += this.ResearchActivitiesBindingSource_PositionChanged;). In the generated method, add a reference to your child datasource and break on it (something like Console.WriteLine(this.researchActivitiesContactsBindingSource);). Have a look on the properties of the bindingsource and tell us what values are in the Count and Current properties when you add a new record (should be Current = null and Count = 0)

Comment: Thanks. Something weird happened. Added the event. current is null and count is 0, but now datagridview cleared up. It's blank. However, I have two problems now. First, I am able to add only one row to the child datagridview. When I try to add the second it complains of the contraint and says the parent must exist. When I add the first row to the child dgv, it correctly shows parent (temp) id as -1. However, when I save the records, only the parent gets stored. I have both constraint and the relationship in FK__ResearchActvityContacts__ResearchActivity

Comment: Do you have the AllowNew set to True for your researchActivitiesContactsBindingSource ? Can you share the code of the method you use to save data back to database ? Assuming you are working with a DataSet, you should call the tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll to save child records.

Comment: private void researchActivityBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            moveFromCheckedListBoxItems();
            this.researchActivityBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.researchActivityTeamMembersBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.researchActivityContactsBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.cRM2DataSet);
      }

Comment: I can see you are calling a moveFromCheckedListBoxItems() method and we don't know what it does. You also have another bindingsource as I can see. Seems to be more complex than expected. The best is for you to try in another form a simple binding between the 2 bindingsource you are interested in. A fresh start is sometimes the best thing to do. As from what I read in the code you shared and your feedback, it should work as expected.